# How to go to a mark in a different file without closing current file in Gvim

Tags: vim

The title says it all. I have marked a line with 'A in onefile.txt. When I open it from secondfile.txt, it opens onefile.txt and goes to the line marked 'A. But, in the process, secondfile.txt is closed.

How can I set up that secondfile.txt remains open and onefile.txt is opened in a separate tab or separate window? I could not find it on seaching the net. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the current window and jump to that mark:

```
:vs
'A
```

or:

```
:vs|norm 'A
```